# javascript:window.open(window.clickTag) opens double tabs in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, tabs, double, clicktag

I am using clickTags in my code for tracking. This is my setup.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var clickTag = "https://www.example.com";
</script>

<a href="javascript:window.open(window.clickTag)">
---Content---
</a>
```

The issue is with Firefox opening double tabs when I click on the link. I only want it to open to the information that is associated with the link. My question, is there a workaround or is there a bug with Firefox?

Comment: When you say "opening double tabs" do you mean that it is opening a *second* tab or that it is opening a *second* and a *third* tab?

Answer (score 2):

For this i would create a function (see below)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clickTag() {
    return "http://example.com"
    }
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="window.open(clickTag()); return false;">Link</a>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3kdcyrbe/

Comment: Thank you for the response and answer but this worked better for me.

onclick="javascript:window.open(window.clickTag)

Answer (score -1):

javascript:window.open(window.clickTag) was what i got from coding from my website and then copying it after it finilized. :)